# Kernel Oops dump: why is the stack data missing?

Tags: linux, kernel, dump

I wanted to see what the kernel Oops dump looks like, so I just embedded a NULL deference in a simple module and tried to trigger it. However, unlike most of the examples online (e.g. [this one](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.15/admin-guide/bug-hunting.html#notes-on-oops-tracing-with-klogd)), my oops message did not include the data on the stack. Is it because that I didn't configure the kernel correctly, or is it because some specific type of error won't have the Stack information in the oops message? My environment: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS + Linux v5.9.

```
kernel: [1585687.978117] BUG: kernel NULL pointer dereference, address: 0000000000000000
kernel: [1585687.978122] #PF: supervisor write access in kernel mode
kernel: [1585687.978126] #PF: error_code(0x0002) - not-present page
kernel: [1585687.978129] PGD 0 P4D 0 
kernel: [1585687.978137] Oops: 0002 [#5] SMP PTI
kernel: [1585687.978144] CPU: 3 PID: 28365 Comm: cat Tainted: G      D    OE     5.9.0+ #1
kernel: [1585687.978148] Hardware name: LENOVO 90HV001MUS/36EB, BIOS O3QKT3DA 05/29/2020
kernel: [1585687.978156] RIP: 0010:scull_read1+0x9/0x1b [scull]
kernel: [1585687.978162] Code: 00 00 00 00 eb f7 0f 1f 44 00 00 55 48 89 e5 5d c3 0f 1f 44 00 00 55 48 89 e5 b8 00 00 00 00 5d c3 0f 1f 44 00 00 55 48 89 e5 <c7> 04 25 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 b8 00 00 00 00 5d c3 0f 1f 44 00
kernel: [1585687.978167] RSP: 0018:ffffb42781e3fea0 EFLAGS: 00010282
kernel: [1585687.978172] RAX: ffffffffc0dd808a RBX: 0000000000020000 RCX: ffffb42781e3fef0
kernel: [1585687.978176] RDX: 0000000000020000 RSI: 00007ff8c902e000 RDI: ffff8c987eec0000
kernel: [1585687.978179] RBP: ffffb42781e3fea0 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: ffff8c987e3d0340
kernel: [1585687.978182] R10: ffffb42781e3fe68 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: 0000000000000000
kernel: [1585687.978186] R13: 00007ff8c902e000 R14: ffffb42781e3fef0 R15: ffff8c987eec0000
kernel: [1585687.978190] FS:  00007ff8c9050540(0000) GS:ffff8c99a6580000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
kernel: [1585687.978194] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
kernel: [1585687.978198] CR2: 0000000000000000 CR3: 0000000004076004 CR4: 00000000003706e0
kernel: [1585687.978201] Call Trace:
kernel: [1585687.978212]  vfs_read+0xa7/0x190
kernel: [1585687.978219]  ksys_read+0xa7/0xe0
kernel: [1585687.978225]  __x64_sys_read+0x1a/0x20
kernel: [1585687.978233]  do_syscall_64+0x37/0x80
kernel: [1585687.978239]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xa9
kernel: [1585687.978243] RIP: 0033:0x7ff8c8b59151
kernel: [1585687.978249] Code: fe ff ff 48 8d 3d 3f 9b 0a 00 48 83 ec 08 e8 66 4a 02 00 66 0f 1f 44 00 00 48 8d 05 91 08 2e 00 8b 00 85 c0 75 13 31 c0 0f 05 <48> 3d 00 f0 ff ff 77 57 f3 c3 0f 1f 44 00 00 41 54 55 49 89 d4 53
kernel: [1585687.978253] RSP: 002b:00007ffd8d944b88 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000000
kernel: [1585687.978258] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 0000000000020000 RCX: 00007ff8c8b59151
kernel: [1585687.978261] RDX: 0000000000020000 RSI: 00007ff8c902e000 RDI: 0000000000000003
kernel: [1585687.978264] RBP: 0000000000020000 R08: 00000000ffffffff R09: 0000000000000000
kernel: [1585687.978268] R10: 0000000000000022 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 00007ff8c902e000
kernel: [1585687.978271] R13: 0000000000000003 R14: 00007ff8c902e00f R15: 0000000000020000
kernel: [1585687.978276] Modules linked in: scull(OE) btrfs blake2b_generic xor zstd_compress raid6_pq ufs qnx4 hfsplus hfs minix ntfs msdos jfs xfs libcrc32c cpuid rfcomm ccm cmac bnep nls_iso8859_1 snd_sof_pci iwlmvm snd_sof_intel_byt snd_sof_intel_ipc snd_sof_intel_hda_common snd_soc_hdac_hda mac80211 snd_sof_xtensa_dsp intel_rapl_msr snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof mei_hdcp snd_hda_codec_hdmi intel_rapl_common snd_hda_ext_core snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_hda_codec_generic x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp snd_soc_acpi ledtrig_audio snd_soc_core coretemp btusb i915 libarc4 snd_compress btrtl ac97_bus btbcm snd_pcm_dmaengine btintel kvm_intel bluetooth kvm iwlwifi crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg snd_hda_codec ghash_clmulni_intel snd_hda_core aesni_intel crypto_simd cryptd glue_helper snd_hwdep efi_pstore rapl snd_pcm drm_kms_helper intel_cstate input_leds wmi_bmof snd_seq_midi intel_wmi_thunderbolt snd_seq_midi_event cec snd_rawmidi snd_seq drm
kernel: [1585687.978402]  ecdh_generic ecc cfg80211 snd_seq_device i2c_algo_bit fb_sys_fops snd_timer syscopyarea sysfillrect mei_me snd sysimgblt mei acpi_tad acpi_pad mac_hid soundcore sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_logitech_hidpp hid_logitech_dj hid_generic uas usbhid usb_storage hid ahci e1000e libahci wmi video [last unloaded: scull]
kernel: [1585687.978463] CR2: 0000000000000000
kernel: [1585687.978469] ---[ end trace 3350b6a415ac3a6e ]---
kernel: [1585688.081953] RIP: 0010:0xffffffffc0de4093
kernel: [1585688.081956] Code: cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc <cc> cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc
kernel: [1585688.081957] RSP: 0018:ffffb42781e6fea0 EFLAGS: 00010282
kernel: [1585688.081958] RAX: ffffffffc0de408a RBX: 0000000000020000 RCX: ffffb42781e6fef0
kernel: [1585688.081959] RDX: 0000000000020000 RSI: 00007f3e58367000 RDI: ffff8c987efdfe00
kernel: [1585688.081960] RBP: ffffb42781e6fea0 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: ffff8c9875710340
kernel: [1585688.081961] R10: ffffb42781e6fe68 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: 0000000000000000
kernel: [1585688.081962] R13: 00007f3e58367000 R14: ffffb42781e6fef0 R15: ffff8c987efdfe00
kernel: [1585688.081963] FS:  00007ff8c9050540(0000) GS:ffff8c99a6580000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
kernel: [1585688.081964] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
kernel: [1585688.081965] CR2: 0000000000000000 CR3: 0000000004076004 CR4: 00000000003706e0
```

Comment: It's up to the kernel configuration options, yes. The basic info is there (registers and the crash site at vfs_read+0xa7/0x190). For the rest, go to "Kernel Hacking" submenu in menuconfig and click on things (debug info, frame pointers, etc).